# Windows stuck at both normal and safeboot

Tags: windows-7, boot, safe-mode

It's been a long time since I have been messing up with my computer but this time it got worse normally when I am stuck at normal booting I .safe boot but this time safe boot is stuck at CLASSPNP.SYS

Help will be appreciated so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`classpnp.sys` is used by Windows for interaction with hardware devices.

Remove all unnecessary hardware
 e. g.

- USB thumb drives
- USB hard disks
- joysticks
- headsets
- webcams
- additional keyboards when using a laptop

Try booting again.

If that works, try to find out which hardware created the problem by plugging in one, reboot, plug in the next, reboot, and so on.

If that does not work, the main suspect is the hard disk.

Boot your computer from a Windows or Linux live media (DVD, USB drive).

If there is very sensitive data on your PC, consider cloning the disk before you run the next steps.

If using a Windows live media, use `chkdsk /f /r` multiple times. This will scan your harddisk for errors and repair them. One run of `chkdsk /f /r` might correct a set of errors and find others, so run it multiple times.

Reboot after that and look whether you can start now. If you can start, depending on the age of your harddisk, consider

- reinstalling Windows on the same harddisk.
- buying a new harddisk and reinstall there.

Comment: Yeah,it worked I live booted Kali Linux and restarted

Comment: Excellent! I am almost sure that Kali Linux contains the `ntfsprogs` package. You could now go ahead and unmount your Windows partition (if mounted) and run `ntfsfix /dev/sdXY`, where sdXY is your Windows partition, e. g. /dev/sdd2.

Comment: Did checking the file system work for you, too?

Comment: Yeah!but new problem born the led is beeping with red color I used to fix that temporarily

Comment: OK... so, can you boot into Windows now? Which LED is blinking? If there is a beep from the speakers, are they rhythmic, like  short-short-long?

Comment: Yeah 5 continues red beeps I can fix it by replacing memory stick but its not permanent

Comment: Have a look in your operating manual or on the BIOS manufacturer's website. Usually, you will find a list with "beep codes" and their corresponding meaning. It will give you an additional hint on what might be wrong. I can't tell you, because I don't know your PC/BIOS manufacturer.